# Chart a PairedHistogram from two columns of a Dataset

Tags: dataset, visualization

I'm currently experimenting using the Titanic example data set:

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}]
```

I'm able to extract a specific column and then chart, for example, a histogram for it:

```
titanic[Histogram, "age"]
```

However, the trouble started when I wanted to construct a `DistributionChart` for two of these columns, say `age` and `class`:

```
titanic[DistributionChart, {"class","age"}]
```

This produces as many chart elements as there are observations. I just want the chart to have two elements: one for "class" and one for "age".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think the problem is that the values in question are not the same for "age" and "class".  For the same reason you could not combine histograms for "temperature" and "cost", or "length" and "weight"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the values in question are not the same for "age" and "class". For the same reason you could not combine histograms for "temperature" and "cost", or "length" and "weight".

You can of course make two histograms that have the same attribute, for instance only "age" or only "weight" or only "length" as here:

```
data1 = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 200];
data2 = RandomInteger[{10, 30}, 400];
Histogram[{data1, data2}]
```

But in your case you must make two separate graphs (because you cannot plot the *class* "1st", "2nd", "3rd" on the same axis as the *age* 10, 11, 12, ...):

```
titanic[Histogram, "age"]
```

or

```
BarChart[Counts[Sort[titanic[[All, 2]]]]]
```

and

```
BarChart[Counts[titanic[[All, 1]]]]
```

Comment: Ok, so it should work if I had let's say two columns both indicating age?

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of problems to overcome to get this to work: the data needs to be transposed, and *class* is not numeric.

**Problem #1: the data needs to be transposed**

The subquery `{"class","age"}` produces a pair of elements (strictly: an association with two elements).  Thus, we end up presenting `Histogram` or `DistributionChart` with a list of pairs.  But to get the desired result, we must instead supply two lists of individual values.

We can accomplish this by transposing the data before plotting it:

```
titanic[Transpose /* DistributionChart, {"class", "age"}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Hmmm, the *class* distribution is blank.  This just brings us to the second problem...

**Problem #2: *class* is not numeric**

The *class* values in the Titanic dataset are not numeric and so will be ignored by `DistributionChart`.  That is why we only see one distribution, for *age*.

For illustration purposes, we will create a second dataset that adds another numeric column containing the *age* skewed by a random offset:

```
titanic2 = titanic[All, <| #, "skewedAge" -> #age + RandomInteger[{-10, 10}] |> &]
```

Now, we can see how transposition solves the first problem:

```
titanic2[Transpose /* DistributionChart, {"age", "skewedAge"}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This works for `Histogram` as well:

```
titanic2[Transpose /* Histogram, {"age", "skewedAge"}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

**Alternate Approach**

As an alternative to using `Transpose`, sometimes we can apply query operators at a higher level to produce two independent lists of values instead of one list of pairs.  For example, we could use `GroupBy` to split the Titanic dataset into groups based upon *sex*, and then plot the resulting values:

```
titanic[GroupBy["sex"] /* DistributionChart, All, "age"]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Labels would probably be useful here:

```
titanic[GroupBy["sex"] /* (DistributionChart[#, ChartLabels->Keys[#]]&), All, "age"]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

> I just want the chart to have two elements: one for "class" and one for "age".

Here is an alternative way to plot that relation [using the package MosaicPlot.m](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/mosaic-plots-for-data-visualization/):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MosaicPlot.m"]

ageQF = Piecewise[{{1, -Infinity < ##1 <= 5}, 
   {2, 5 < ##1 <= 14}, {3, 14 < ##1 <= 21}, {4, 21 < ##1 <= 28}, 
   {5, 28 < ##1 <= 35}, {6, 35 < ##1 <= 50}, {7, 50 < ##1 <= Infinity}}, 0] &;

ageQFRules = {1 -> "1(under 6)", 2 -> "2(6...14)", 
   3 -> "3(15...21)", 4 -> "4(22...]28)", 
   5 -> "5(29...35)", 6 -> "6(36...50)", 
   7 -> "7(50+)", 0 -> "0(missing)"};

titanic2 = 
  titanic[All, 
          <|#, "qage" -> If[Head[#age] === Missing, 0, ageQF[#age]] /. ageQFRules|> &];

MosaicPlot[titanic2[All, {"class", "qage"}], 
 "LabelRotation" -> {1, 0.5}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]